# wxPython StyledTextCtrl and shortcuts

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla, wxstyledtextctrl

I use StyledTextCtrl in wxPython application and faced with a problem. Main menu 
has shortcuts like Ctrl+Alt+C, Ctrl+Alt+... In Windows is all OK, but 
in Ubuntu when user pressed this shortcut, StyledTextCtrl adds control 
characters ("SOH", "STX", "ETX" etc) and menu item is not activated.

If shortcut has no Alt key then everything is fine.

How can I fix it? wxPython 3.0.2. Ubuntu 16.10 + Unity.

A similar behavior is observed in the wxPython demo application.